# Likelihood ratio test in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy, statistics

I am having trouble computing a likelihood ratio test in Python 2.7.

I have two models and the corresponding likelihood values. I believe the rule for comparing whether model L2 is better than model L1 (if the models are closely related) is to look at -2 * log(L2/L1).

I then want to find the p-value for corresponding to -2 * log(L2/L1) and relate this to the significance for L2 is preferred to L1. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import chisqprob

L1 = 467400. # log(likelihood) of my 1st fit
L2 = 467414. # log(likelihood) of my 2nd fit

LR = -2. * np.log(L2 / L1) # LR = -5.9905e-05

p = chisqprob(LR, 1) # L2 has 1 DoF more than L1

print 'p: %.30f' % p # p = 1.000000000000000000000000000000

five_sigma = 1 - scipy.special.erf(5 / np.sqrt(2.))                  :-)
print '5 sigma: %.30f' % five_sigma

five_sigma_check = 1 - 0.999999426696856                             :-(
print 'Check  : %.30f' % five_sigma_check
```

However, I run into two issues:

- My p-value is coming out to be 1 when I'd have expected it to be close to 0.
- When I use the formula on the line marked with the :-) to find five sigma, for example, it differs from the value quoted in the literature - that line is highlighted with a :-(. My value for `five_sigma_check` is taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule#Table_of_numerical_values).

Can anyone offer any advice, please? I'm relatively new to the world of Python and statistics.

Thanks.

Comment: Are `L1` and `L2` likelihoods or log likelihoods? If they're log likelihoods, you shouldn't be taking the log of them when calculating LR

Comment: `L1` and `L2` are the logs of the likelihoods. I see what you mean, taking the log of the logs doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To calculate the likelihood ratio given the log-likelihoods, use this formula:

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
def likelihood_ratio(llmin, llmax):
    return(2*(llmax-llmin))


LR = likelihood_ratio(L1,L2)


p = chi2.sf(LR, 1) # L2 has 1 DoF more than L1

print 'p: %.30f' % p 

# p: 0.000000121315450836607258011741
```

Comment: chisqprob does not exist anymore with scipy or it is not importing at all for me. Everything else in scipy works (using verison scipy-1.0.0). Is there another method for this?

Comment: I believe the new equivalent function is `scipy.stats.chi2.sf()` – perhaps you could update your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a little bit theory, so that it will be helpful for someone to understand:

[image]

Here we have two models (assuming nested) and we want to compare the effectiveness of the models in terms of explaining the data. From the above figure, let's now implement the LR test with python 3:

```
from scipy.stats import chi2 
ll_0, ll_1 = 467400, 467414 # given, the log-likelihoods of the nested models m_0, m_1
# log likelihood for m_0 (H_0) must be <= log likelihood of m_1 (H_1)
Λ = -2 * (ll_0 - ll_1)
print(Λ)
# 28.0
df = 1 # given the difference in dof
# compute the p-value
pvalue = 1 - chi2(df).cdf(Λ) # since Λ follows χ2
print(pvalue)
# 1.2131545083660726e-07
```

We can plot and clearly see that we can reject the NULL hypothesis in favor of model m1, at α=0.05.

```
α, df = 0.05, 1
x = np.linspace(0, 30, 1000)
plt.plot(x, chi2(df).pdf(x), label='χ2')
plt.axvline(chi2(df).ppf(1-α), color='red', label='α=0.05')
plt.scatter(Λ, 0, color='green', s=50, label='Λ')
plt.legend()
plt.title('χ2({}) distribution'.format(df), size=20)
```

[image]