# statsmodels metric for comparing logistic regression models?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I'm learning about logistic regression by building models in `statsmodels`.

I know that if I build a linear regression model in statsmodels, `lin_mod = sm.OLS(y_var, X_vars).fit()`, I can easily get the adjusted R-squared `lin_mod.rsquared_adj`. I find adjusted R-squared pretty helpful when comparing my linear regression models.

Now for logistic regression models, `log_mod = sm.Logit(y_var, X_vars).fit()`. I know there is a pseudo-R-squared metric, `log_mod.prsquared`, but I don't find it very convincing. Is there some other easily accessible metric in `statsmodels` that might be helpful for comparing logistic regression models?

Answer (score 0):

In `statsmodel` you could go with

```
print(lin_mod.summary())
```

to gather more informations about your model.
Otherwise, if you could use `sklearn.metrics`, try with `confusion_matrix` or/and `accuracy_score`

Answer (score 0):

Prof. Frank Harrell in his blog [Statistically Efficient Ways to Quantify Added Predictive Value of New Measurements](https://www.fharrell.com/post/addvalue/#ref-sch03pre) describes in detail different options for quantifying the added value of predictor in the new model and visually inspecting pre- and post-test probabilities. Pseudo-R squared is indeed difficult for interpretation.

However, you can use the likelihood ratio test, where log-likelihoods of two models are compared. **The important assumption is that the models are nested**, meaning the larger model should contain all predictors from the smaller model + a new predictor.
[image: Likelihood Ratio test]
or
[image]
Multiplication by -2 ensures the chi-squared distribution (Wilks theorem), therefore we could calculate a p-value.

Here is my code for that inspired by [Likelihood ratio test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38248595/likelihood-ratio-test-in-python). It outputs chi2-statistic and p-value similarly to a lot of `scipy.stats` tests for the ease of reporting.

```
from scipy.stats.distributions import chi2
from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import BinaryResultsWrapper
import statsmodels.api as sm 


def likelihood_ratio(ll0, ll1):
    return -2 * (ll0-ll1)

def lrtest(fitted_model0: BinaryResultsWrapper, 
           fitted_model1: BinaryResultsWrapper) -> (float, float):
    
    L0, L1 = fitted_model0.llf, fitted_model1.llf
    df0, df1 = fitted_model0.df_model, fitted_model1.df_model
    
    chi2_stat = likelihood_ratio(L0,L1)
    p = chi2.sf(chi2_stat, df1-df0)

    return (chi2_stat, p)

log_mod0 = sm.Logit(y_var, X_vars0).fit()
log_mod1 = sm.Logit(y_var, X_vars1).fit()

chi2_stat, p = lrtest(log_mod0, log_mod1)
```

Comment: Hi @crusher083, is the lr-statistic the same for OLS regression and logistic regression? 
Why is that not implemented in statsmodels?